# How to start batch file from the top left corner of the screen?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Is there any command to make a batch file start from the top left corner by default so that I can conviniently resize it using this command:

```
mode con: cols=50 lines=50
```

I want the batch window to start like this:

[image]

Comment: In the command line properties, right click left upper corner properties.Tab: Layout, in lthe "Window Position options"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line